# html form input array

Tags: javascript, html

Looking for some help on whether there's a smarter way I can make my form work, using arrays.

I have a form where you either need to enter details of a person's weekly, fortnightly or monthly salary and overtime. If you enter a weekly basic salary, I want to disable all the fortnightly and monthly salary and overtime fields.

In my HTML each field has a name e.g.

And my javascript so far for disabling fields is:

```
if (document.getElementById("basic_sal_weekly").value >0) { 
    document.getElementById("basic_sal_fortnightly").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("basic_sal_4weekly").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("basic_sal_monthly").disabled=true;
} else {
   document.getElementById("basic_sal_fortnightly").disabled=false;
}
```

However I'm sure there's got to be a quicker way of doing this, than manually typing out every single field in my HTML document.

Comment: classnames do wonders! Select by classname and loop.

Comment: Does get elementsbyclass work in IE6? 

I've tried


 document.getElementsByClass("").disabled=true;

but I get the error messsage;

object doesn't support this method

Comment: IE6????? [Who supports IE6](http://www.modern.ie/ie6countdown)? There is no getElementsByClass method in any browser. There is document.getElementsByClassName which returns a collection and there is querySelectorAll. Both have limited early IE support.

Comment: Ah sorry I did try the getElementsByClass name but that didn't work either. I know, unfortunately it's got to support IE 6 which is totally archaic

Comment: Well even itf it did support it, you can not set an attribute on a collection, you would need to loop. `var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("foo"); for( var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) { elems[i].disabled = true; }`

Comment: Most companies have dropped IE6 and IE7 and are about to drop IE8. You are probably coding for one user. lol

Comment: AH yes but unfortunately, we're running on an intranet with thousands of internal users still on IE 6 lol

Comment: Are the elements grouped in any way? is there a common element around them?

Comment: I have tried the following to update all elements with class a but that doesn't work either. Any ideas?                                 var number =document.getElementById('basic_sal_weekly');
  
  var update_fields = function () {
 
 
 if (number > 1) {
        $('.a').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('.a').removeattr('disabled');
    }
  };

  $("#basic_sal_weekly").change(update_fields);

Comment: number is an object not the value and removeAttr has a capital A. The code is as simple as `$(".a").prop("disabled", $("#basic_sal_weekly").val() > 1);`

Comment: Thankyou - prop did the trick!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just give your fields the same class and disable all elements with this class..

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery:

```
<script src="objects/codes/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#your_element_id").removeAttr("disabled"); // enable
    $("#your_element_id").attr("disabled", "disabled"); // disable
</script>
```

[Download the uncompressed, development jQuery 2.0.3](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js)